# Is this kind of DB relation design favourable and correct? Should it be converted to a no-sql solution?

Tags: nosql, rdbms

*First of all, I did my research but being rather a newbie, I am not that well acquainted with words so might have failed in founding the correct ones. I beg your pardon in case of a possible duplicate.*

**Question #1:**

I have a table consisting of `ID [PK] and LABEL [Varchar 128]`. Each record (row) here is unique. What I want is, to define relations between these LABELS.

Requisite:

There will be an ***n*** amount of groups, each group containing one or more of these LABELS. In each group, each LABEL can either exist or not exist (meaning a group does not have 2x of same LABEL).

How should I define this relation?

I thought of creating another table with `ID [PK] - Group ID [randomly assigned unique key] - LABEL_ID [ID of Labels table pointing to a single Label]`

**Is this correct and favourable?** If a group has 10 LABELS then there will be 10 records with unique ID, same uniquely assigned `Group ID and LABEL_ID` pointing to LABELS table.

Question #2:

**Should I let go of the Relational solution (as described above) and opt for a NoSQL solution?** Where Each group is stored on it's own as a single entry into the database with an `ID [PK] - Data [Containing either labels or IDs of labels pointing to the Label table]?`

If NoSQL is the way to go, how should I store this data?

a) Should I have ID - Data (containing Labels)?
b) ID - Data (containing IDs of Labels)?

Question #3:

**If NoSQL solution here is the best way, which NoSQL database should I choose for this use case?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is too little information here to make recommendations on the question of "to SQL or not to SQL".

However, the relational approach would be as you describe, I think.

```
CREATE TABLE Group
(
    GroupId int PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE GroupLabel
(
    GroupId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Group,
    LabelId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Label,
    UNIQUE (GroupId, LabelId)
)

CREATE TABLE Label
(
    LabelId int PRIMARY KEY,
    Value varchar(100) UNIQUE
)
```

Here, every label is unique, Many labels may be in each group and each label may be in many groups but each label can only be in each group once.

As @Damien_The_Unbeliever indicates, the `Group` table can be omitted if you don't need to store any additional attributes about each group by making the `GroupId` column on the `GroupLabels` table solely unique.

You might need to change the syntax slightly for whatever RDBMS you're using.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this answer. I forgot I guess though to add that a Label might be in more than one group.

Comment: @Phil I've updated my answer to take this many-many relationship into account.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real need for an `ID` column in this `GroupLabels` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE GroupLabels (
     GroupID int not null,
     LabelID int not null,
     constraint PK_GroupLabels PRIMARY KEY (GroupID,LabelID),
     constraint FK_GroupLabels_Groups FOREIGN KEY (GroupID) references Groups,
     constraint FK_GroupLabels_Labels FOREIGN KEY (LabelID) references Labels
)
```

By doing the above, we've automatically achieved a constraint - that the same label can't be added to the same group more than once.

With the above, I'd say it's a reasonably common SQL solution.

Comment: Thank you. But what happens when a Label needs to be in more than one group? And could you please explain what you did here?

Comment: The label can be in more than one group - they'll use different `GroupID`s - but what's been prevented is having the *same* pair of `GroupID` and `LabelID` appear more than once.